# How do I send output to the console instead of a document when knitting

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I want to be able to send information to the R console for a user to see when I am knitting a document. So for example, I have a code chunk:

```
<<descriptive, child = 'descriptive.Rnw'>>=
@
```

But before this, I would like to return the line "Beginning the descriptive section..." to the console. So my question is, how do I send a code chunk to the R console instead of the LaTeX document?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your operating system?

Comment: also, one question per question is the policy here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a unix system, hide a chunk of code that calls `system` to echo a message:

```
<<fnord,results="hide",echo=FALSE>>=
system("echo '\\n****** hello world *******\\n'")
@ 
<<runme>>=
x=1:10
y=runif(10)
plot(x,y)
@
```

The first chunk spits out a message to the console, the second runs normally. Note use of a single quoted string to stop shell expansion of the stars, and the escaped \n to make a newline. The show and echo options stop the chunk appearing in the output.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks very much that works perfectly. It's always so obvious when someone points it out to you. Thanks again. I will re-post my second question.

Comment: @Natty_E, if you are satisfied with this answer, please tick the answer on left so that it is marked as resolved